# Creating a full join in SQL without duplicates

Tags: sql, join, full-outer-join

I have two tables, both of which have a date field. What I want as an end result is a table of dates (can be duplicated) with records A and B in that row.

```
id_a     date_a
1        Jan 1
2        Feb 2
3        Feb 2
4        Mar 3
```

```
id_b     date_b
a        Jan 1
b        Feb 2
c        Mar 3
d        Mar 3
```

```
date     id_a    id_b
Jan 1      1       a
Feb 2      2       b
Feb 2      3       null
Mar 3      4       c
Mar 3      null    d
```

I currently have this solution, but instead of the null fields, it would duplicate id_a : 4 and id_b : b.

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(Table1.date_a, Table2.date_b) AS date

Table1.id_a, 
Table2.id_b

FROM Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2
  ON Table1.date_a = Table2.date_b;
```

Answer (score 0):

[DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f4505e9897cb5c612291d096b959566a)

I added a match on the `row_number` of the date:

```
SELECT  
   COALESCE(a.date_a, b.date_b) AS date,
   a.id_a,
   b.id_b
FROM 
   (SELECT
       id_a,
       date_a,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date_a ORDER BY id_a) R
   FROM table1) a
FULL OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT
       id_b,
       date_b,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY date_b ORDER BY id_b) R
   FROM table2) b ON a.date_a = b.date_b and a.R = b.R
```

output:

| date | id_a | id_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | 1 | a |
| 2021-02-02 | 2 | b |
| 2021-02-02 | 3 |  |
| 2021-03-03 | 4 | c |
| 2021-03-03 |  | d |

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks a lot!